# How to install java JDK (not JRE) on CentOS 5.4?

Tags: centos, java, yum

How can I install java JDK on CentOS 5.4 using yum?

I have JRE only, but it's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't do it with `yum`. I had to do it manually, downloading JDK and installing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Java Development package group using

```
# yum groupinstall "Java Development"
```

Comment: FYI, this installs GCJ, not the Oracle/Sun JDK.  Use `yum groupinfo "Java Development"` for more information.

Comment: And I'm getting JDK 1.4, instead of 1.5.. Can I get 1.5 somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Download the JDK rpm-bin version, unpack it, wrap it into your own repository, add the repository to your CentOS and then install.

Or use `yum localinstall RPM`. Why did you ask this?

We do something along the above lines to be able to distribute JDK-Updates to all our CentOS servers using yum-cron.